# Include icon as default in mdframed

Tags: mdframed, fontawesome, fancybox

**Problem:**

Not being able to create a generic solution that includes a Font-Awesome icon as default for a `frametitle` using `mdframed`.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[medfamily,textosf,mathlf,mnsy,amsbb,mixedgreek,minionint,openg,footnotefigures]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{MnSymbol,pifont}
\usepackage[onlytext,medfamily,osf]{MyriadPro}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\linespread{1.25}

\definecolor{spotcolor}{cmyk}{1,0,0,0}

\newcommand{\colfancyhead}{spotcolor!40}
\newcommand{\colfancybox}{spotcolor!5}

\newcommand{\mdneedspace}{5\baselineskip}

\mdfdefinestyle{mddefinitionstyle}{%
  linewidth=0pt,%
  roundcorner=0pt,%
  frametitlerule=false,%
  apptotikzsetting={%
    \tikzset{mdfframetitlebackground/.append style={fill=\colfancyhead}}%
    \tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style={fill=\colfancybox}}%
  },%
  frametitlefont={\sffamily\bfseries\small\strut},%
  theoremtitlefont={\sffamily\small},%
  frametitleaboveskip=3pt plus 1pt,%
  frametitlebelowskip=2pt plus 1pt,%
  innertopmargin=7pt plus 1pt minus 1pt,%
  innerbottommargin=8pt plus 1pt minus 1pt,%
  outermargin = 0pt,%
  innermargin = 0pt,%
  splitbottomskip=10pt,%
  splittopskip=14pt,%
  needspace=\mdneedspace,%
  skipabove=14pt plus 2pt minus 6pt,%
  skipbelow=14pt plus 2pt minus 6pt%
 }

\newmdenv[style=mddefinitionstyle]{fancybox}

\begin{document}

\begin{fancybox}[frametitle=\faExclamationCircle \nobreakspace\nobreakspace Note]
Lorem ipsum
\end{fancybox}

\end{document}
```

**Desired outcome:**

An icon is per default included in the frametitle of every fancybox.

Thanks in advance for the guidance in solving this issue.